# Suppose $X_1, . . . ,X_n$ are a random sample from a population whose density function is $f(x|β) = \frac{β}{x^{β+1}}$ , $1 < x < ∞$, $β > 0$.

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

For the distribution, $f(x|β) = \frac{β}{x^{β+1}}$ , $1 < x < ∞$, $β > 0$.

> (a) Find the uniformly most powerful test of $H_0 : β = 1$ against $H_1 : β < 1$.

I have found it as $\prod{X_i} > c$ via likelihood ratio test.

> (b) Conduct the test, giving a $p$-value and stating your conclusions clearly, based on
> the following 20 observed values:
> 1.23 2.74 4.99 5.11 5.55 6.55 138.80 1.90 4.74 2.53 
> 2.41 1.21 26.55 6.81 1.17 1.39 1.08 4.87 2.91 2.57

I was struggling to find the distribution of $\prod X_i$ to calculate $p$-value, are there any good ideas?

Comment: I wonder how $\log(X_i)$ and $\log(\prod X_i)$ might be distributed

Comment: It may work, I'll do a calculation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your hint [@henry](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6460/henry) , I may have a result post as below.

For question (a)

> Consider a simple statistical hypotheses, $H_0:\beta = 1$ against $H_1:\beta=\beta_1<1$. Then the likelihood ratio is as
> $$
> \frac{L(1)}{L(\beta_1)}=\frac{1}{\prod{x_i^2}}\frac{\prod{x_i^{\beta_1+1}}}{\beta_1^{n}}=\frac{\prod{x_i^{\beta_1-1}}}{\beta_1^{n}}
> $$
> Let the ratio
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> \frac{L(1)}{L(\beta_1)} &\leq k \\
> \frac{\prod{x_i^{\beta_1-1}}}{\beta_1^{n}} &\leq k \\
> (\beta_1-1)\sum\ln{x_i} &\leq \ln{k}+n\ln{\beta_1}\\
> \sum\ln{x_i} &\geq c
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> Hence we get a *uniformly most
> powerful region* for testing.

For question (b)

> Let us consider the distribution of $Y=\ln{X}$ first. Using the transformation equation of pdf we have
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> f_Y(y) &= f_X(g^{-1}(y))|\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)| \\
> &= \frac{\beta}{e^{\beta y+y}}e^y \\
> &= \beta e^{-\beta y}
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> Which is a exponential distribution $Exp(\beta)$ or a gamma distribution $\Gamma (1,\frac{1}{\beta})$, so we know the distrubution of sum of y
> $$\sum{y_i}=\sum{\ln{x_i}} \sim \Gamma (n,\frac{1}{\beta})$$
> According the observed data, we can finally calculate a *p-value* as follow:
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> p &= P(\sum{\ln{X_i}} \geq \sum{\ln{x_i|H_0}}) \\\\ 
> &= P(\sum{\ln{X_i}} \geq 26.5321|\beta = 1) \\\\
> &= 1-F_{\Gamma}(x=26.5321,\alpha=20,\beta = 1) \\\\
> &= 0.08088
> \nonumber
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> where $F_{\Gamma}$ is the cdf of gamma distribution.
> So we can reject $H_0$ at confidence level $\alpha = 0.1$, but accept it if $\alpha = 0.05 $

Comment: How does this answer the question?